# Consequences of a $Parity$ $P$-problem being reducible to a sparse language?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, p-vs-np, unary-languages

$Parity$ $P$ is the class where an $NP$-machine answers $YES$ if and only if the number of accepting paths of that turing machine is odd.

With regards to the $P$ vs $NP$ question, there is a theorem by Mahaney which says that there is a sparse, $NP$-complete language iff $P=NP$.

Does there exist a similar theorem for $Parity$ $P$?
Specifically, if one could find a sparse language in $NP$, such that some $NP$-complete problem's $Parity$ $P$-version can be reduced to that sparse language, would $Parity$ $P=P$ follow?

Comment: (i) "Reduced" using what kind of reduction $f$, exactly?  For example (working from #CNFSAT), a poly-time computable function $f$ such that for every CNF formula $x$ the number of satisfying assignments for $x$ is odd if and only if $f(x)$ is in the sparse language?  (ii) Presumably Mahaney's proof (or a simplification of it such as https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.05825) is not easy to adapt to this?  Can you explain why?

Comment: This does not imply anything, as there are NP-complete problems whose $\oplus$P versions are in P (e.g., because the number of witnesses is always even), and therefore reducible to a singleton language. If the question is to make any sense, you have to at the minimum require that the $\oplus$P version is $\oplus$P-complete. But this still does not feel right, as there may be perhaps exceptions when the NP version is NP-complete for a "different reason" than that the $\oplus$P version is $\oplus$P-complete. A safer assumption is that the #P version is #P-complete under parsimonious reductions.

Comment: On the other hand, why do you ask the sparse language to be in NP? Mahaney's theorem actually holds for arbitrary sparse languages (i.e., if an NP-complete language reduced to a sparse language, or IOW if there exists an NP-hard sparse language, then P = NP), but even if you insist on including such a restriction, shouldn't the $\oplus$P analogue ask the sparse language to be in $\oplus$P rather than NP?

Comment: A terminological note to avoid potential confusion (which I was also sloppy about in the comments above): there is no such thing as a “$\oplus$P version of an NP problem”. A given NP problem will have many different verifiers which will correspond to many different $\oplus$P languages with very different properties. Rather, a given *verifier* (say, a nondeterministic poly-time TM, as you use this formalism) has an associated #P function $C(x)={}$the number of accepting paths, an associated NP language $\{x:C(x)>0\}$, an associated $\oplus$P language $\{x:C(x)\equiv1\pmod2\}$, etc.

Comment: @NealYoung I do mean poly-time reductions liket that.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I find the scenario interesting where we can use a sparse language in NP because it could mean two things: Parity P is included in NP and reducible to a sparse language. I am sorry for the impreciseness of the question. The main idea is that there is a natural NP-complete problem, like Hamiltonian Path, for which we can check the existence of Hamiltonian paths iff there is an odd number of Hamiltonian Paths, by reducing to that sparse language.

Comment: Reducing a $\oplus$P-complete problem to a sparse language in particular reduces it to a P/poly language, which implies that $\mathrm{ModPH_2\subseteq P/poly}$ and $\mathrm{ModPH_2=MA\cap coMA}$. If you further assume the sparse language is in NP, then $\mathrm{\oplus P\subseteq NP\cap coNP}$, but this does not seem to imply further collapse of $\mathrm{ModPH_2}$. This is all before one even starts to think whether sparseness can be leveraged in a stronger way as in the proofs of Mahaney’s theorem (and I can’t see whether that will work or not).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek What is ModPH_2?

Comment: See https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:M#modph